# accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier returning nil for Twitter under iOS 5

Tags: ios, null, ios5

I'm having problems with one method we use for Twitter access.  More specifically with the method:

```
- (ACAccountType *)accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)typeIdentifier
```

This method is working properly under iOS 6, but is returning `nil`under iOS 5.  There is no indication in the documentation of when such behaviour is to be expected, nor is there any indication that this method is unsupported under iOS 5.

A snippet of my code:

```
- (void)preferredAccountWithSelectionHandler:(SSTwitterHelperAccountSelectionHandler)selectionHandler
{   
    ACAccountType* accountType = [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
    {
         // Some more code
     }];
}
```

Intuitively I suppose this method should never return nil, even if no accounts are configured, as it just returns the account type, which is shared across all accounts of the same type.

Comment: Did you end up finding out what was going on? All of a sudden I've been getting this problem when it used to work before!

Comment: My solution was to simply accept it can be nil, if the user hasn't set up a Twitter account, and adding a check for this.  This is not documented anywhere (so I recommend you run some tests too), but it fixed my problem.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing too. Cheers.

Comment: What do you mean to accept that it can be nil? also for me it's nil - but the method requestAccessToAccountsWithType seems not to return anything :(

Comment: @Odelya - See my answer below! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question.  I just added an IF condition in case it returns nil, which seems to be a valid outcome.

```
- (void)preferredAccountWithSelectionHandler:(SSTwitterHelperAccountSelectionHandler)selectionHandler
{   
    ACAccountType* accountType = [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    if (accountType)
    {
        [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
        {
             // Some more code
         }];
    }
    else
    {
        // No accounts for the type specified
    }
}
```